# MDX aggregation and where clause fundamentals

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have this very simple query:

```
select [Measures].[MyMeasure]  on 0,
[MyDimension].[MyHierarchy].[MyMember] on 1
from MyCube
```

and I am getting a number in the intersection (for example `1500`).

Then, I wrote the same query a little bit different:

```
select [MyDimension].[MyHierarchy].[MyMember]  on 0
from MyCube
where [Measures].[MyMeasure]
```

And I still get 1500.

But when I change a query like this:

```
select [Measures].[MyMeasure]  on 0
from MyCube
where [MyDimension].[MyHierarchy].[MyMember]
```

The result of the query is empty.

But I do not understand why, since as I understand, the context of the cell is the same, or not?

When I run this query:

```
with member measures.test as [MyDimension].[MyHierarchy].currentmember.name 
select {[Measures].[MyMeasure],measures.test} on 0 from MyCube where 
[MyDimension].[MyHierarchy].[MyMember]
```

For `MyMeasure` result is empty, and for test measure result is `MyMember`.

Comment: 1) Can you share the result of the following query. with member 
measures.test 
as 
[MyDimension].[MyHierarchy].currentmember.name
select {[Measures].[MyMeasure],measures.test}  on 0
from MyCube
where [MyDimension].[MyHierarchy].[MyMember]   2)Is the measure a calculated measure. If so it can have a script that is altering the result

Comment: Thanks @MoazRub, I have edited the question to include result of your query

Comment: what about the second question ")Is the measure a calculated measure". Because ideally the context of the cell is same.

Comment: It is not calculated measure.

Comment: this is strange. The cell context is same. Can you share your orignal query?